# In EF 4.0, Is static class to get the dbcontext is a good way to go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I would like to know if it's a good practice to create a static class to get the Entity Database Context.

This`GetEntity()` return the Context. In the `GetEntity` method, I have a dynamic connection.
When someone go to my login page, they need to provide a database number + Username + Password. I stock the dbname in  `Session["DBName"]`.

```
public static class EntityFactory
    {
        public static DBEntities GetEntity()
        {
            var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            scsb.DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"];

            scsb.InitialCatalog = "db1";
            scsb.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            scsb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["DBName"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/Step1");
            }
            else 
            {
                scsb.InitialCatalog = HttpContext.Current.Session["DBName"].ToString(); 
            }

            var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            builder.Metadata = "res://*/nms.bin.Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/nms.bin.Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/nms.bin.Models.DBModel.msl";
            builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            builder.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString;
            DBEntities db = new DBEntities(builder.ConnectionString);
            return db;
        }
```

When I want to get the DBContext by example in a controler, I Just need to do `EntityFactory.GetEntity()` and that returns me a DB context.

1. Is it Correct the way I do this
2. Is that could be a problem if 20 clients log at the same time but with a different dbname.
3. For the moment, I'm not using any dispose, Is it a problem? Based on my `EntityFactory` Class, can I make a global disposable in that class that will be call automaticly. (I think about the descrutor method).

Comment: @Eranga thanks a lot for editing , my english is not good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order :

1. You can improve it by passing to `GetEntity()` all the info it needs (like the dbname, username and password). As it is now the static method is tightly coupled with the session. Move the session out from the method.
2. It should not as the Session is per user.
3. If `DBEntities` inherits from `DbContext` you can call the Dispose after you've used the object. Es: `dbEntitiesObj.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

The `static` factory method can be difficult to mock for unit testing. So fro example in your controller if you had:

```
public void SomeControllerMethod()
{
    var entities = EntityFactory.GetEntity();
    return entities.Something // ... get whatever data...
}
```

Then how would you use a mocked data context in a unit test? It would be difficult to do.
It would be better to "inject" your context into your controller, typically through the constructor (Read the Wikipedia article on the "[dependency inversion principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)" if you aren't familiar with the concept), like:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly IDBEntities entities;

    // db context passed in through constructor,
    // to decouple the controller from the backing implementation.
    public void SomeController(IDBEntities entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
}
```

And then have the controllers methods use that passed in reference. This way you can use a dependency injection tool to get the appropriate db context, or pass in a mocked context.

I'm not sure if MVC2 had a good way to add a dependency injection framework though, but I know MVC3 does.

Your approach works too, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with it, it just seems harder to test. Of course if you aren't doing any unit testing and don't need to use a mock data store, then I guess it really doesn't matter :)

I typically end up using MVC3 with EntityFramework Code-First, which turns out pretty nice, and you can mock most of the data layer with `List<T>` instead of the actual database, you can "load" and "save" records to in-memory lists and never touch the real database.